# How do I actually create a .NET Core project in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Maybe this is super obvious and I just can't find it but how can I create a .NET Core project in Visual Studio (2015 or, preferably, 2013)? I just want to run a console application on a Linux machine. The documentation at on the [.NET Core github page](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/index.html) is incomplete and anything from Microsoft provides little-to-no help.

Bonus points if you can also tell me an easier way to run the application from my Linux command line other than `dotnet run` while sitting in the directory of the application.

Comment: Has the question resolved by now? RC2 tooling for Visual Studio 2015 is available and works. You can create a new Project with the standard new project dialog. Victor also deserves the answer, at the time of the question the answer was right.

Answer (score 25):

.NET Core templates are available in [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2017). When installing VS2017, you have to pick the ".NET Core cross-platform development" workload. Once you do, you'll have access to the templates:

1. Click **File - New Project**.
2. Expand **Visual C# - .NET Core** on the left side.
3. Pick one of the templates.

[image: .NET Core templates in Visual Studio 2017]

---

If you're on Visual Studio 2015, make sure you install [Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) (or later) and the [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core). Then the templates will show up in **New Project**:

[image: New .NET Core Project in Visual Studio 2015]

---

It's also possible to scaffold new applications on the command line, using either `dotnet new` (included with the .NET Core SDK), or [`yo aspnet`](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet#generator-aspnet):

```
# Create a new console app
dotnet new

# Create a new web (ASP.NET Core) application
dotnet new -t web

# Use generator-aspnet via yeoman
yo aspnet
```

Comment: It bugs me that it still says .NET Framework 4.6.1 up top.  You'd think it would say a .NET Core version instead since the standard library is different between the two and there are multiple versions of .NET Core.

Comment: @Powerlord Yeah, the GUI is non-intuitive right now. Hopefully it'll be fixed in VS 2017.

Comment: After installing SDK one should install Preview tools for VS 2015 to display templates. download from [HERE](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546)

Comment: I have Update 3 and Core SDK, but there is no .Net Core option in list of projects in my VS 2015...

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov Maybe the templates weren't installed for some reason. Try VS 2017 perhaps?

Comment: Yes, @Vara, with VS2015 I had to install update3 + .Net Core SDK + Preview Tools.  Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

1. VS 2013 doesn't support CoreCLR at all.
2. VS 2015 doesn't support `dotnet` yet but it supports `dnx`

Both on Windows and Linux you can run `dotnet new` to create a console app.

Comment: ....Seriously? Why did they even bother creating the API Port utility? "This console application *could* work on Linux if we supported it". Doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Are you trying to build a dnx or dotnet based app?

Comment: I don't know(/care). I want to run a console application in Ubuntu. I've done the `dotnet new` and `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` thing, and that's cool but as soon as I add anything more than "Hello World" to the console application (something like a `File.ReadAllLines`) it stops working. I figured Visual Studio would be smarter (and easier) to develop in instead of nano. The application doesn't exist yet.

Comment: If you don't want to use `dotnet` and you're okay with `dnx`, then in Visual Studio you can create a Console Application (Package) under Templates -> Visual C# -> Web. That will give you a console app. Then you can follow the instructions [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html) to get the runtime on Linux